# How to convert MongoDB collection to class using v 2.7.3

Tags: c#, mongodb

My packages:
MongoDB.Driver 2.7.3(latest)
MongoDB.Bson   2.7.3(latest)

here is my class:

```
public class Details {
    public Object _id { get; set; }
    public string domain { get; set; }
    public string retailerId { get; set; }       
    public string channelId { get; set; }
}
```

here is my codes to get the colelction:

```
        var client = new MongoClient(con);
        var database = client.GetDatabase("testdb");
        var collection = database.GetCollection<Details>("testcollection");
        //this doesnt get anything
        var details = collection.AsQueryable<Details>();
        //this will do the work but its in List
        var details = collection.AsQueryable<Details>().ToList();
        //Deserialization that wont work
        var details = MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializer.Deserialize<Details>(collection);
```

What am I missing to successfully convert the collection value to my class without making it ToList().

PS: Bson Deserializer doesnt work with error: cannot convert from 'MongoDB.Driver.IMongoCollection' to 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument'

Comment: You cannot get results without `ToList()` or `ToListAsync()`. Where are you seeing the other error? By trying to access your line that did not call that method?

Comment: what error? the cannot convert ?

Comment: Considering that is the only error mentioned in your question, then that would probably be what I am asking about. Instead of the snippet in the question, try posting some more complete code demonstrating what you expect to happen along with details of any errors it produces.

Comment: Do you mean that you want a single document?

Comment: @John yeeees...